# Using Struts tag within HTML tag for hiding/displaying table

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, ognl

I want to hide a table on load of a page and hide it on click of a button on that page.I have created a property of type String in Action class named as `"displayTablle"` and assigned it a value `"none"` by default.So that when this page is opened by calling action,this property will be none and following code used in table tag should hide the table:

```jsp
<table border="true" id="dataTable" style="display:"<s:hidden id="disTable"   name = "displayTable" value="%{displayTable}"/>;"> 

<s:submit value="Fetch Data" align="center" action="displayDataAction" />
```

Then on click of Fetch Data button, I am setting value of this property to blank string i.e `" "`, so that table will be displayed, But I am stuck with the syntax and `<s:hidden>` is not getting bound properly, as when I open the page, last part of the table tag's code i.e `;">` is getting printed as is.

Can anybody suggest, what should be the right syntax to bind s:hidden in html table tag? Can we do it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `property` tag is used to write text to the JSP page. It has also option for unescaping that text, but it's not required in your case.

```jsp
<table border="true" id="dataTable" style="display:<s:property value='%{displayTable}'/>;">
```